# AttributeError: 'SpatialReference' object has no attribute 'ImportFromESPG'

Tags: python, coordinate-system, osgeo, attributeerror

I am trying to create a spatial reference using ImportFromESPG and this is what is returned:

AttributeError: 'SpatialReference' object has not attribute 'ImportFromESPG'

Code and error are copied below. I copied this code exactly from the cookbook: https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/projection.html
so it seems that something must be wrong with my installation?

Windows 10, Python 2.7.8 with IDLE. I get a very similar error when I use python in the command window where the canopy install of python is my default (python version 2.7.11).

Python 2.7.8 comes from the ArcGIS install (10.3.1 with 64bit geoprocessing update).  I installed GDAL from the gisinternals website. Both versions of python on my system are MSC v.1500 64 bit. For Canopy, gdal is installed internally as a package.

Code and error:

```
from osgeo import osr
sr=osr.SpatialReference()
sr.ImportFromESPG(29613)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
    sr.ImportFromESPG(29613)
AttributeError: 'SpatialReference' object has no attribute 'ImportFromESPG'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sr.ImportFromEPSG()`

You have the S and P transposed.

For the record, I don't see an entry for EPSG::29613 so that code may be invalid or deprecated.

http://epsg.io/?q=29613

Comment: I feel a little silly. And the 29613 is also transposed... it should be 26913 (UTM13N, nad83). Thank you!